# Membership GetUser() returns null with User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, login-control

This is strange but in my application Membership.GetUser(), Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name) returns null but Membership GetUser(Login.UserName) works fine. I am using .Net 4.5 but with old asp.net membership. Could anyone explain why is this behavior?

Comment: Are you doing this in your login method?

Comment: Membership GetUser(Login.UserName) is after successful login. The other two are in other files of the project.